# Puppeteer 'EvaluateOnNewDocument' equivalent in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

i have to make an extension.

this extension must hide browser-automation data. so i have to override some readonly properties (navigator.webdriver, navigator.plugins, ...)

it works well with puppeteer. when i put this code into Page.EvaluateOnNewDocuemnt function, that properties successfully overrided.

but how do same thing on chrome extension? i searched up many articles, but everything fails. ex) put same code in popup.js / put same code on contentScript, setInterval, ... everything fails.

```js
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
  get: () => false,
 });
```

Comment: You need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm You are my savior.